# Mysql join function to join around 25 tables

Tags: mysql

I have around 15 tables in my database. 
Each table has a column employee id's, I wanted to join all the tables based on employee id column and at the same time select two columns from each table.
That means finally, I will have a table with 31 columns. (1 id column and 30 from 15 tables)
What would be the easier way to do this?

Comment: we need more information here.  If some of the tables are many-to-one or one-to-many relationships, then the joins are different, depending on what you want for a result

Comment: You want to create a query that returns rows from multiple tables or you want to merge tables into a single table?

Comment: I want to merge that into a single table

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend you to use(whenever is possible) a [left join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) to achieve that. In that link you can have an idea of how to optimise the process, because, of course, you will need it a lot. Anyway, depending on the amount of data you have, please consider redesigning the database. Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, one possible solution could be:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.f1, t1.f2, t2.f3, t2.f4, ....., t15.f30, t15.f31
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id....
....
INNER JOIN table15 t15 ON t1.id = t15.id
WHERE ....
```

Naturally IDs must have indexes (for faster querying); I'm assuming one-one relation, but this standard query could be easily changed to fullfil your needs...